# Nested RESTful routes not working (RoutingError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble nesting my routes. It would probably be easiest to show you the code. Here is my routes.rb file:

```
resources :leagues do
  get 'delete', :on => :member

  resources :league_relations do
    get 'delete', :on => :member
  end
end
```

Each League has_many :league_relations, and each LeagueRelation belongs_to :league. The delete route there is just a confirmation before the destroy action.

I am trying to use Rails' path helpers, but they are not working for some reason. Specifically, I am trying to do this:

```
new_league_league_relation_path
```

But this raises the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"league_relations"}

Technically, the error is correct. There is no route matches 'league_relations#new', but shouldn't the URL created by this helper be

> /leagues/:id/league_relations/new

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I actually figured out the problem. The solution was just to pass in a League into new_league_league_relation_path. My code ended up looking like

new_league_league_relation_path(current_league) 

where current_league is a helper that returns the league currently being looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually route is exactly as you expect it to be. You just forgot to add :league_id

This will work:

```
new_league_league_relation_path(:league_id => 1)
```